# Can I reference multiple elements using aria-describedby?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

If I have two elements that together describe one element, can I use two ids on `aria-describedby` attribute like this?

```html
<div id="description-1"></div>
<div id="description-2"></div>
<div aria-describedby="description-1 description-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. The [aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby) (and aria-labelledby) attribute expects an [ID reference list](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#typemapping) as it's value. Multiple IDs can be provided, separated by spaces. When you associate multiple elements in this way, they are concatenated into a single description string.

A few things to watch out for:

- Punctuation. If the 2 referenced elements are intended as separate sentences, it helps to put include a full stop (period) so that screen readers can announce it more naturally. Alternatively, you can use multiple references to build up a sentence. It depends on your scenario.
- `aria-describedby` isn't effective on all elements. In your example the attribute is on a `div` element, which generally doesn't work. It works better when used on interactive elements and landmark regions. See [Short note on aria-label, aria-labelledby, and aria-describedby](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2017/07/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/) for guidance.
- The referenced elements will form part of the accessible description regardless of whether they are visible. Be careful if associating error messages this way. See  [Hidden or visible – makes no difference](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2015/05/short-note-on-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/) for guidance here.

For further details, see the [Accessible Name and Description Computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aam-1.0/#accessible-name-and-description-computation) rules in HTML Accessibility API Mappings 1.0.

Comment: When trying to figure out if the "ID reference list" was space-separated or comma-separated, I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute

Comment: Good point @FrancisA - my answer didn't say what the separator is. It is indeed a whitespace separated list. I'll edit my answer to say that.

Comment: Interstingly, the ARIA recommendation doesn't say what separator to use either! It's worth filing an issue with the W3C ARIA itself to clarify that.

Comment: Ah, it turns out the "whitespace-separated" format IS already explained in the ARIA 1.1 recommendation, in Appendix B: [Mapping WAI-ARIA Value types to languages](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#typemapping).  I'll edit my answer to link to that.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby

> Identifies the element (**or elements**) that describes the object